# Call a PHP Function at a particular time

Tags: php, curl

So as the title says, I'd like to trigger a PHP Function(Particularly a cURL Function) at a particular time, eg. 10AM EST 18/08/2021. How could I go about doing this, I've found very little to no documentation on this anywhere.

I could also add that if a Discord Bot is required(As the cURL Function goes to Discord) I could always do that as well, but just a few pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: just run a cron (scheduled) job on your server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: @CornelRaiu Thanks! Yes it did answer my Question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use cron.

On a Linux server, login and do `crontab -e`.

This is from the documentation that came with my crontab:

```
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').

# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```

So, in your case, you would do:

```
0 10 18 08 * php script.php
```

Comment: This was really helpful, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Generally you're supposed to upvote helpful answers on SO.  Let us know if you need further clarification.

Comment: My bad, will bear that in mind for the future. Still fairly new to this! Sorry.